Utilizar JNA para acceder a funciones de un DLL en Java
Tengo un DLL (SyncSDK.dll) el cual fue proporcionado por una empresa externa. Este DLL debería darme funcionalidades para poder conectarme y pedir datos a un dispositivo. En primera instancia estuve probando el DLL en Python, llame las funciones y me servían. Por necesidades de la empresa tuve que cambiar el lenguaje de desarrollo a Java, en este creé nuevamente las funciones y las probe y no me sirven.
La documentación para la definición de las interfaces está en Pascal, y la función que quiero utilizar es esta:
function SDK_Initialize: Boolean; stdcall;
Function: Dynamic library initialization
Parameters: empty
Return value: Bool type. True means initialization is successful, False means
initialization fails.

Mi código en python en el que la función SDK_Initialize() me sirve es este:
lib = ctypes.CDLL("./SyncSDK.dll")

SDK_Initialize = lib.SDK_Initialize
SDK_Initialize.restype = ctypes.c_bool

if SDK_Initialize:
print(SDK_Initialize)
print("Conexion Exitosa!")

Lo cual me retorna un valor True.
Sin embargo, en Java solo me devuelve False, el código en Java es este:
public interface SyncSDK extends Library {

    SyncSDK INSTANCE = (SyncSDK) Native.load((Platform.isWindows() ? "SyncSDK":"syncsdk"), SyncSDK.class);
    
    boolean SDK_Initialize();
}


public class SyncSDKImpl implements SyncSDK {
    //Metodos que implementan la interfaz
    
    @Override
    public boolean SDK_Initialize() {
        System.out.println("Inicializando SDK...");
        return SyncSDK.INSTANCE.SDK_Initialize();
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SyncSDK syncSDK = null;
        try {
            syncSDK = new SyncSDKImpl();
            boolean init = syncSDK.SDK_Initialize();
            if(!init) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Fallo al inicializar el SDK"); 
            }
            
        } finally {
            syncSDK.SDK_Finalize();
        }
    }
}

Y me salta el error cuando SDK_Initialize() retorna False.
Muchas gracias.

¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Mencionas que hay un error, pero no indicas cuál es y, como puedes comprender, esta información es vital para poder entender cuál es el problema y probablemente sea el punto de partida para que un experto en tema pueda ayudarte a resolver la situación en que te encuentras. De otra forma, se hace muy difícil responderte. Encontrarás más información en [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Una observación, no se si será un typo al pegar el código, pero en la versión de Python no veo que estés llamando a la función en ningún momento. if SDK_Initialize: va a retornar True siempre, SDK_Initialize es un objeto (¿FuncPtr?)  que se va a evaluar como cierto siempre (en general todos los objetos se evalúan como True), otra cosa es if SDK_Initialize():, eso si evalúa el retorno de la función y no el "objeto función" en si.
